# ActiveRecord has_one and has_many relation with the same :foreign_key

Tags: ruby, activerecord, cancan, has-many, has-one

I have two models, `Story` and `Chapter`. A story `has_many` chapters, one of those is a chapter which serves as its first chapter. I used to have a foreign key `start_id` in the stories table to indicate which chapter is the first. Hovewer, the the database schema had to be changed a little, now every chapter has a `code`. If the code is `'1a'`, then that is first chapter of the story which owns the chapter.

The following seems to work, including `#create_start`:

```
has_many :chapters, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :story
has_one :start, :class_name => 'Chapter', :foreign_key => 'story_id', :conditions => {:code => '1a'}
```

This way, the foreign key `start_id` of the stories table is unneeded, and `#start` still remains an association, with all the benefits (I need `#start` as an association, because I use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) with associations for authorization).

Does my approach has any drawbacks that I currently fail to realize, or I am relatively safe with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relying on the code == '1a' to find the first chapter is a bit wonky. I'd probably add a flag to the chapters table like 'first_chapter' or something that was true or false indicating whether it was the first chapter. This way the first_chapter-ness of a chapter would survive a change to the code field, but this is a bit nitpicky.

Also, to avoid repeating yourself, you could change the declaration of has_one :start to something like:

```
has_one :start, :through => :chapters, :conditions => { :code => '1a' }
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know `:through` could be used not only for join models, but also subsets. That's definitely cleaner.

Comment: ...except that CanCan suddenly stopped working after I re-created my development database. If I revert to the more verbose association, it's all good again. How odd.